# Does it duplicate data because of not deleted events Kafka topic?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

I am new at kafka and consumed about event deletion.
Kafka does not delete the events in topics. But deletes them after some retention time.

For example I have a consumer and a producer application on a dotnet core platform. Producer puts the `Order` data, and consumer gets and save it to the database. But the topic is not deleted. If consumer application is restarted, will it start from zero and duplicate the database records? How can we prevent this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [offsets](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> This offset acts as a unique identifier of a record within that
> partition, and also denotes the position of the consumer in the
> partition.
>
> ...
>
> The committed position is the last offset that has been stored
> securely. Should the process fail and restart, this is **the offset
> that the consumer will recover to**.

Make sure you that the consumer is committing the offset and upon restart, it will use the same offset to continue consuming a topic.